# Bootstrap, как при Collapse сделать другое меню?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток! Существует следующий вопрос по **Bootstrap**. 
Предположим есть вот такое меню[image: Меню до раскрытия]

Как мы видим, есть кнопка на которой имя пользователя, соответственно кликнув по нему, получаем список.
[image: Меню, с раскрытым Dropdown-Menu]

При маленьком разрешении экрана, меню автоматически убирается в Collapse.
[image: Collapse меню при маленьком разрешении экрана]

Соответственно кликнув по кнопке, мы получаем следующий результат
[image: Результат клика по Collapse на маленьком разрешении]

Если сейчас кликнуть на Пользователя, то получается вот такое
[image: Результат открытия Dropdown Menu при Collapse]

Вопрос стоит в следующем как же можно при маленьком разрешении экрана сделать нечто похожее на это? Грубо говоря, те элементы, которые в dropdown menu, надо развернуть уже автоматически и чтобы это выглядело цивильно) 
[image: Желаемый результат при Collapse]

Comment: Через @media прописываете нужный диапазон разрешений и стилями приводите кнопки в нужный вам вид, а для самого dropdown установите `display: block;`. Пожалуй, надо еще добавить `position: static;` для dropdown.

Comment: @Игорь, спасибо, попробую!